# linq "let" division, then orderby ascending

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-excel

I have this data, and I'm using linqToExcel:
[image]

I'm trying to get inflation divided by GDP...then order them ascending, but I can't get it right.

```
    var people = from x in excel.Worksheet<CountryEconomics>("Sheet1")
                 let c = x.Inflation / x.GDP
                 orderby c ascending 
                 select c;
```

I'm getting the output:

```
12
6
4
3
2
2
```

no matter if I put ascending or descending in the query. How can I get the data ascending? i.e.

```
2
2
3
4
6
12
```

Comment: So what's the question? Stuck somewhere?

Comment: _I can't get it right_ -- what output are you getting and what are you expecting?

Comment: I can't get it to orderby ascending, sorry.

Comment: You should still update your question to fully define _it_.

Comment: Are GDP or Inflation the result of a formula?  If so, do you have similar results when they are not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, I'm just guessing, but maybe adding some casts will make it work:

```
var people = from x in excel.Worksheet<CountryEconomics>("Sheet1")
             let c = ((double)x.Inflation) / ((double)x.GDP)
             orderby c ascending 
             select c;
```

However if that fails as well - what'll happen if you make it a list first:

```
var people = from x in excel.Worksheet<CountryEconomics>("Sheet1").ToList()
             let c = ((double)x.Inflation) / ((double)x.GDP)
             orderby c ascending
             select c;
```

If that's still failing:

```
var people = from x in excel.Worksheet<CountryEconomics>("Sheet1")
             let c = ((double)x.Inflation) / ((double)x.GDP)
             select c;

var peopleList = people.ToList().OrderBy(p => p);
```

Hope this gets it done...

Answer (score 3):

[MSDN orderby clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383982.aspx)

```
var people = from x in excel.Worksheet<CountryEconomics>("Sheet1")
             let c = x.Inflation / x.GDP
             orderby c
             select c;
```

---

I can't reproduce with just an array:

```
var economics = new[]
    {
        new {Country = "USA", GDP = 1, Inflation = 12},
        new {Country = "GB", GDP = 2, Inflation = 12},
        new {Country = "JPN", GDP = 3, Inflation = 12},
        new {Country = "GER", GDP = 4, Inflation = 12},
        new {Country = "CHI", GDP = 5, Inflation = 12},
        new {Country = "CAN", GDP = 6, Inflation = 12},
    };

var people = from x in economics
             let c = x.Inflation/x.GDP
             orderby c
             select c;

// without "orderby c":  12, 6, 4, 3, 2, 2
// with "orderby c":  2, 2, 3, 4, 6, 12
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", people));
```

---

It could be a flaw with Linq-to-Excel.  (I'm not in a position to test this.)

If that's the case, you could force the evaluation (via `.ToArray()` below) and then sort it.  As a consumer of any static data with LINQ, I would *expect* the `ToArray` call to be unnecessary.

```
var people = from x in economics
             let c = x.Inflation/x.GDP
             select c;

var sorted = people.ToArray().OrderBy(c => c);
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", sorted));
```

Comment: If I add "orderby c ascending" on the 3rd line, I get the same output as if I had put descending.

Comment: @marseilles84:  see my comment on the question.  You _really_ need to state what you're receiving compared to what you're expecting.  We don't know what _it_ is.

Answer (score 2):

If all you want is to sort by `Inflation / GDP`, you can just do this:

```
var people = from x in excel.Worksheet<CountryEconomics>("Sheet1")
             orderby x.Inflation / x.GDP
             select x;
```

Or in fluent syntax:

```
var people = excel.Worksheet<CountryEconomics>("Sheet1")
                  .OrderBy(x => x.Inflation / x.GDP);
```

I'm not sure, but you may need to skip the first row (which has the headers).

```
var people = excel.Worksheet<CountryEconomics>("Sheet1")
                  .Skip(1).OrderBy(x => x.Inflation / x.GDP);
```